# getting the contents of a function in an `onclick` attribute in my html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What?!  I know, what a bad idea.

Firstly I have no control over the html that was output, its from a vendor and it is produced via their crazy system that our company has an agreement with. (let's not talk about the situation, I know it's not optimal)

In the html I have:

```
<a id="notify" onclick="location.href='index.php?foo=bar';return false;" href="javascript:;">Notify!</a>
```

In my JS If I do:

```
console.log($("#notify").attr("onclick"))
```

I recive:

```
onclick(event)
```

Which makes sense, but I need to change the onclick's attribute, so it reads to something like:

```
onclick="location.href='index.php?foo=bar&zoobazz=moo';return false;"
```

better yet, if I could remove the onclick and replace the href attributes value with location.href.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the function in a string

```
$("#notify").attr("onclick").toString()
```

Grep the URL after that

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I posted with a fully functioning example. I guess it pays to be concise and to the point. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to actually see what the onclick event is doing and append to it, not just replace it. I tried this in chrome and it works, but it's pretty much a hack. Basically, when you get a reference to the "click" or "onclick" event function (using either jQuery or pure JS), then you can to a ".toString()" on it to convert the function into a string. Then you just strip off the "function" definition using some trickery and you're left with what you need - "location.href='.......".

Then just append your additional parameters. Hopefully this leads you in the right direction.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $target = $("#notify");
    var funcBody = $target.attr("onclick").toString().split("\n")[1].split(";")[0];
    $target.attr("onclick","").attr("href", funcBody);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="notify" onclick="location.href='index.php?foo=bar';return false;" href="javascript:;">Notify!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set onclick by using $("#foo").click = '';
You can change href by changing the attribute, using .attr(key, value);
http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes, and http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax

so

```
$('#foo').click = '';
$('#foo').attr('href', 'whateveryousetitto');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('notify').onclick = function() {location.href='index.php?foo=bar&zoobazz=moo';return false;};
```

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
$("#notify").click(function() { $("#notify").attr("onclick", "location.href='index.php?foo=bar&zoobazz=moo';"); return false;})
```

not do what you need it to do?

Comment: We'll the problem is the onclick attribute is output by the server, so I need to get its value, and manipulate it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading too much into the question, but I think OP is asking how to get the event code so that it can be manipulated, not just replaced.  When specifying "index.php?foo=bar", I don't think the value of bar is known.  If this was a known value, then why read the onclick value at all?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to know. I am well aware of how to use attr(), thanks for clarifying +1

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('#notify').click);
```

?